# Android the real object has been deleted

Tags: android, android-emulator

i have an activity and from that i am calling another activity using following function

startActivityforresult(i)

from the result too i m passing another parameters and calling that intent again but after 5-6 calls it says that the real object has been deleted,, and the previous intent don't do the things it is made to do on the condition,,,,

any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Please show us some code and the stack trace you obtain.

Comment: You should work other way around, its actually androids default behaviour..