# "The real object has been deleted" in logcat

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

This question was previously asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362216/android-the-real-object-has-been-deleted), but not answered, And failed to find any article on the web that explains this issue.

My app is working fine, but at some point when i `startActivityForResult` i see
3 logs of `webcoreglue: The real object has been deleted`.

Now allegedly my app is all ok so far, and i have no idea what and why this message is being logged.

Could someone explain why and when this is happening and what does it mean, before i try and find out what's wrong with my app?

**EDIT:**
On the request for more context, i'm not using any special libs i think, only the Facebok SDK.

My app at the moment is a "Create game" activity which has 3 options, invite players from facebook, invite player by username and add random player.

The invite players from facebook button opens a ListActivity (for result) that returns all the players you select. invite user opens dialog box with EditText and searches the server for the user data.
All the selected players appear in a ListView inside the main activity, so add random player just adds an item to that listview.

I belive the error may be, that i'm using a static field in the main activity in which i try to use from the ListActivity.

the ListActivity gets a Parcelable that contains a class which contains 3 ArrayList of image,name and id.
that parcable contains all the selected users from all 3 methods.
Hope this is enough context, don't know what more can i say as i have no clue of what that log is related to.

**EDIT 2:**
After another search foudn [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819690/webcoreglue-android) question which gave a specific solution toa problem

Comment: we need more context. What does your app do? do you use any libs, graphics or something else that could help us?

Comment: does it cause any other problems except the log print out such as exceptions, etc? Does it always happen or just sometimes? If it always happens can you please post some code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It allways happens, and i do have some errors that passing between the activites mess up the selected players order and re-adds selected players again. i edited the question with an explination as to Pedro's request. Theese are big files and i don't know which parts to publish, if i print them all it's too much code for any human eyes.

Comment: My mistake - it dosen't always happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something went out of scope and it's destructor was called. Search for "The real object has been deleted." showed only a specific solution for a screen rotation artifact and a hack  for overriding some of the object destructors. It would be educational to put print statements in your object destructors to see what is getting called and when.